# Issue deploying Django project to Apache via WSGI

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Ubuntu 14.04.4 and
Django 1.10

I'm trying to deploy a simple Django app that works perfectly in development to Apache, via WSGI. The relevant bits in my Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost [my IP]>
    WSGIScriptAlias /Django/MedFormUpdates /home/web/inside/django/MedFormUpdates/MedFormUpdates/wsgi.py
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /home/web/inside/django/MedFormUpdates/MedFormUpdates

<Directory "/home/web/inside/django/MedFormUpdates/MedFormUpdates">
        Options ExecCGI
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

In my wsgi.py file:

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/web/inside/django')
sys.path.append('/home/web/inside/django/MedFormUpdates')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MedFormUpdates.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And in my settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MedFormUpdates.wsgi.application'
```

When I attempt loading the page, I get "**We're sorry, the web server had an internal error.**" - with the Apache log showing

```
End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
```

I've been through every Django/WSGI/Apache thread that I can find, and this is driving me nuts. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error message indicates you're trying to run `wsgi.py` as a CGI script (and, unsurprisingly, it doesn't output what CGI program is expected to do). You most certainly don't need `Options ExecCGI`. I'd suggest to backup your existing Apache configs and start off the fresh slate, following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ to the point.

Comment: Will you be running multiple django sites on the mod_wsgi process?

Comment: @AndréTerra - eventually, yes. This is the first one though.

Comment: Are you using virtualenvs? Are you using mod_wsgi in daemon mode?

Comment: Thanks @drdaeman...see my answer below. You pretty much put us on the correct track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we have another Apache configuration file in the directory /etc/apache2/conf-enabled which has the following setting, which binds Python scripts (as well as Perl and CGI) to CGI:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

This is necessary for many other things that we have in production. In order to except my project from that, in my Apache config file I removed

```
Options ExecGI
```

and instead put

```
RemoveHandler .py
```

which now has the page showing just fine.

Answer (score -1):

This question is impossible to answer without more information on

1. the rest of your stack;
2. which dependencies your django project has;
3. which Python versions you have installed;
4. how you installed Python and Apache;
5. how you are running Apache.